# expand macro to select all "txt" files in folder A and save as with the same name in other folder B after processing handling

Tags: vba

EXCEL 2010
Below you can find a written macro that work verry well but it proces only 1 by 1.
The original file has a specific extention and would like to open them with Excel and then execute the code below. Although the saving should be **with maintenance of the original name**, only the extention would be .xlsm. The saving into an other folder is working now but don't maintain the name at the moment. I have seen that some people have asked almost the same questions but I did not found the right answer yet.
I am searching the way to open (with excel) all files *.ext* or *.FUG* folder A , process the macro, save As in folder B **with maintenance of the original name**, but extention .xlsm
Is there a way to simplyfy the macro too?

```
Sub tekst_naar_kolom()
'
' tekst_naar_kolom Macro
'
' Sneltoets: Ctrl+x
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 3), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1)), DecimalSeparator:= _
        ".", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    ChDir _
        "D:\destinationfolder"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "D:\destinationfolder\**save file with same name**.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you open the .ext files? With macro (if so, please present some code) or manually? Am I right that you start above macro when .ext file is imported to one column of any active(!) workbook?

Comment: thank you for the reaction! wel, for now I have to open the files with excel (original other extention), then I have to copy the macro in it. Then when I run this code it wil select the colum/maje the written changes/save the file an .xlsm file. I should do this from another workbook.Therefor I have a workbook where I already installed a object-button and on that command the code have to go too see in a specific folder/ open the file/ do the changes "but" it has to save as "the first sheetname" of the file "or" with the same as the original file (but then in the extention .xlsm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the Windows Scripting Host FileSystemObject, the code below late binds this object and iterates through the files collection of the source folder. When it finds a file ending in .ext or .FUG it processes it and saves it in the destination folder as an .xlsm file.
Just adjust the Source and Destination folders and run it- whatever workbook this code is in will not be changed, it opens and saves the files separately leaving this workbook open during processing.

```
Sub tekst_naar_kolom()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim sSourcePath, sDestinationPath As String
    Dim sFileName, sNewFileName As String
    Dim wbProcess As Workbook

    'set source and destination folders
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sSourcePath = "C:\sourceFolder\"
    sDestinationPath = "C:\destinationFolder\"

    For Each oFile In FSO.GetFolder(sSourcePath).Files
        'if the current file ends with .ext or .FUG process it
        If LCase(Mid(oFile.Name, InStrRev(oFile.Name, "."))) = ".ext" Or _
                LCase(Mid(oFile.Name, InStrRev(oFile.Name, "."))) = ".guh" Or _
                LCase(Mid(oFile.Name, InStrRev(oFile.Name, "."))) = ".fug" Then
            'create the new file name & path
            sNewFileName = Left(oFile.Name, InStrRev(oFile.Name, ".") - 1)
            sNewFileName = sDestinationPath & sNewFileName & ".xlsm"

            'if the same file exists in the destination folder, do not process it
            If Not FSO.FileExists(sNewFileName) Then
                'use WorkBooks.OpenText to interpret the file
                Workbooks.OpenText oFile.Path, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                    Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                    :=Array(Array(1, 3), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
                    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1)), DecimalSeparator:= _
                    ".", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
                Set wbProcess = ActiveWorkbook
                wbProcess.Sheets(1).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                    Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                    :=Array(Array(1, 3), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
                    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1)), DecimalSeparator:= _
                    ".", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

                'autofit all columns, format
                wbProcess.Sheets(1).Cells.Select
                wbProcess.Sheets(1).Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                With wbProcess.Sheets(1).Cells
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                    .WrapText = False
                    .Orientation = 0
                    .AddIndent = False
                    .IndentLevel = 0
                    .ShrinkToFit = False
                    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                    .MergeCells = False
                End With
                'freeze panes
                wbProcess.Sheets(1).Range("A4").Select
                wbProcess.Windows(1).FreezePanes = True

                'save in new folder with new file name
                wbProcess.SaveAs Filename:=sNewFileName _
                    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
                'reset variable for next file
                wbProcess.Close False
                Set wbProcess = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next oFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mr McConeghy, What you have send me excites me a lot! I see that the code is effectively saving in the right extention, but for some reason the proces of tekst to Colum is not processed in the xlsm file. I noticed also that it has not saved in the destination folder, but next to it. For the last part maybe I am dooing something wrong. I ll dubblecheck this. For now thank you for this fantastic thinking!!

Comment: it seems that the tekst to colum is being  made (visual on screen),but when the xlsm file is closed it does not save the proces

Comment: This code runs perfectly on my test files that are simple text files delimited with semicolons. For one thing, make sure that you have a backslash (\) at the end of the source and destination folder paths. If you can't get it working maybe you can post some example files showing what an original file looks like and what the processed file should be.

Comment: backslash problem solved.Forgo 1. Do I have a way to send you the original file that has to be formatted? It seems that I can not find the way to upload a file.

Comment: Ok, I just updated the code above- I added the TextToColumns parse back into the process. The example file was actually not semicolon delimited but each line is. I hope this works. Also, the file extension of the file you posted was .guh, be sure that you add any other file extensions that it may need to parse by duplicating the line `LCase(Mid(oFile.Name, InStrRev(oFile.Name, "."))) = ".guh" Or _`

Comment: YOU ROCK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot!!!!! It work like it should! You are the best Mr McConeghy!! Now figure out how I can vote you the maximum of votes! You earned it!

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help! - Yes I did receive the Answer vote- Thanks! =)

Comment: what can I do now when more files are added to the destination folder and I have to launch the code again? Is there a way to abord copying the early processed files?

Comment: I have revised the code to ignore files if the corresponding file is found in the destination folder.

Comment: Can I post you some further processes to see if that would be possible to add too? Of course if that is ok ?

Comment: I believe this web site is about supporting individuals who want a helping hand as they teach themselves how to program. I suggest researching and trying to accomplish a process on your own first and then coming here when you have not been able to make the process work on your own.

Comment: I understand your point and agree with that. I am a beginner. Therefore I always try first. For the earlier code  I tried for several days other codes and advises from the net, but my case was too specific. I will practise of course first for the other questions. Thats why I did not posted yet :-). My next attempt wil be putting some excel commando's in the code your wrote before closing the files. This will thake some time becouse first I would like to try all the possibilities I can collect on the net.Again, thanks for all advise. I appriciate a lot!

Comment: @user2151190 I strongly encourage you to post new questions specific to the current obstacles you are facing. There are thousands of people that visit this web site and I am certainly not the most qualified to help you with each problem. However, I try to help when I can and have the time.

Comment: I understand and appriciate every sigle help I can get and got already! Take your time. Thanks for answering so fast again Mr McConeghy!! Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Is there a way to let the soucepath chage automaticly when the active workbook+ folders are being copied to an other folder ? The subfolders name will be the same, only the destination will change. Also the main foldername will change. It has to follow the structure of the main and subfolders. I would like to share this workbook without having to rewrite the folderpaths if possible :-(  When I copy this code (with workbook) into an other folder it is not working until I manually change the folder desinations please..

Comment: @user2151190 Look into using `ThisWorkbook.Path` or `Me.Path` where you assign the values of `sSourcePath` and `sDestinationPath`.

Comment: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") sSourcePath = "Thisworkbook.Path\myPath\" sDestinationPath = "ThisWorkbook.Path\myPath\"          trying like this it can not find the path but maybe I am entering it wrong..

Comment: Sorry, but what I ment to write is that I should refer to subfolders after finding the ThisWorkbook.Path . Thanks  a lot for answering again :-)

Comment: @user2151190 In Visual Basic the ampersand symbol (&) is used to concatenate strings. For example: `sSourcePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\myPath\"`

Comment: What a beautiful solution!!!!!!!!!! Like this even the code is a lot shorter and is working a lot more effective! I forgot to try the symbol, my appology. You know this function verry well! Again I learned something new! In my profile there is a question related to this function but I don't know how to integrate it. I opened a new discussion for this and posted also a draft of my workbook. I would be verry pleased if you could help me out. Over 2 weeks I had to start helping other people too but I am not ready with that part of code :-(. Thanks mr McConeghy, you are really amazing!